# File.OpenText() throws a DirectoryNotFoundException on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, streamreader

I am trying to read .csv file on Windows Phone 8. And I am writing below code. This similar code runs on C#. But when I click to run I was getting error.

PivotPage.xaml.cs:

```
List<double[]> inputs = new List<double[]>();
List<double[]> outputs = new List<double[]>();

using (StreamReader okuyucu = File.OpenText(".\\TrainData\\iris_data.csv")) //this is giving error
{

Bla bla bla

}
```

Error: An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Data\Programs{36F60104-9832-417C-AFDC-91B66CB56343}\Install\TrainData\iris_data.csv'.

I am trying ".\TrainData\iris_data.csv" , "\TrainData\iris_data.csv" , " C:\\Users\OSMAN\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\PanoramaApp1\\PanoramaApp1\\TrainData\\iris_data.csv" and another version.

How can I read iris_data.csv file.

Thanks in advance. (sorry my language)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [StorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx) class to load the application resource.

Like this:

```
var uri = new System.Uri("ms-appx:///TrainData/iris_data.csv");
var file = Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```

Comment: What is the build action for iris_data.csv set to, @OsmanVilli ?

Comment: Is it SILVERLIGHT;WINDOWS_PHONE ?

Comment: @OsmanVilli, select the file and then under properties: http://images.cnblogs.com/cnblogs_com/Tealcwu/WindowsLiveWriter/WindowsPhoneBuildAction_E47F/buildaction_thumb.png